# Send gridview in email basics C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, gridview

I would like to create a mail in which a gridview is included. I've been searching the internet and tried multiple solutions. But somehow I'm missunderstanding or doing something wrong. With my current code I get the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Data source is an invalid type. It must be either 
an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.
```

I read about using `StringBuilder`, `StringWriter`, `HtmlTextWriter`, `RenderControl` and so on, but still can't figure out how to make this work.

Here is my code:

```
        public void Email()
    {            
        string conn = "Data Source=pc-..";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conn);
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlCommand sendGrid = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblSomething", sqlConn);

        GridView grd = new GridView();

        if (sendGrid != null)
        {
            grd.DataSource = sendGrid.ExecuteReader();
            grd.DataBind();
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        grd.RenderControl(htw);

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.To.Add("ToWhoEmail");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("FromWho");
        mail.Subject = "SubjectSomething";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.BodyFormat = System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.IsBodyHtml.Html;
        // At this line above i get an error. He doesn't recognize BodyFormat = ...;
        // System.Web.Mail.MailFormat is obsolete.
        // The recommended alternative is: System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.IsBodyHtml
        mail.Body = sb.ToString();
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("...");
        smtp.Send(mail);}
```

I have also tried making the gridview in a different cs file and call it with: 
SendGrid.MakeGrid() in the mail.Body = "...";
But all i get then is: System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView     in my email.
All help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Regards, Mati

Comment: My C# code doesn't recognize IsBodyHtml because i'm using System.Web instead of System.Net i think. But i don't think that's it.

Comment: Srry for editing this much, had to delete personal info.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is on this line:

```
grd.DataSource = sendGrid;
```

You are trying to use a `SqlCommand` as data source to the grid view which is not possible. You could use a data reader or a data set:

```
grd.DataSource = sendGrid.ExecuteReader();
```

Also make sure you dispose those connections and commands properly by wrapping them in [using statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: +1.Nicely spotted!  I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, that's probably due to the poor naming convention used by the OP. Personally I would never name a `SqlCommand` variable `sendGrid`.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Nor me. One of my pet peeves is proper naming of things.

Comment: Hello, i tried your answer, i had to add sqlConn.Open(); and when i tried again i encountered the following error: 

`System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid. --- End of inner exception stack trace --- `

I've never seen this error before and don't know what to do with it. I'm not using a method or something called SendUsing for as far as i know.

Comment: @mati, how does your SMTP server configuration section look like in the web.config? Have you specified a valid SMTP server?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I'm not using my web.config file to send emails so far. I have running code to send emails, but not with a gridview in it. I will now Edit my first uploaded code by my current code. I have now specified my smtpclient in the code, which i stated at Vir his post aswell.

Comment: @mati, but in the code you have posted I don't see you specifying an SMTP server. Without SMTP server you cannot send emails.

Comment: @Everyone: I was finally able to send a gridview in email using this code. Just delete the line where i say that it gives an error and it'll work.

Special thx to Darin Dimitrov, Mitch Wheat and Vir for the help. Cya around. ;)

Comment: @mati, so maybe you could close this thread by marking an answer?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I could, but the real answer isn't between them, these are all hints to get to the solution and I can't post the answer yet. Also because i changed the original code to what it is now (the answer) I can't mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

in your above code i didn't see the smtp settings for the mail sending ....set the port no and the sever access credential like u'r username and password of gmail and port

smtp.gmail.com (use authentication)

Use Authentication: Yes

Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587

Port for SSL: 465

Comment: Hello, ty for your respons. Indeed i noticed i was missing something, I thought it was the `SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("");` which i first used with System.Net.Mail so i started changing things again. Only thing that is showing up as an error atm in my code is : 

`mail.BodyFormat = System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.IsBodyHtml.Html;
            
            // System.Web.Mail.MailFormat is obsolete.
            // The recommended alternative is: System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.IsBodyHtml`

Any idea on how i can fix this pls?

Comment: MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
                    message.IsBodyHtml =false;                       try this and send the mail as mailmessage...may it will help u.

Comment: Hey Vir, thank you for looking into this. I solved it by just deleting the row, how silly a solution can be right.

Answer (score 1):

and for the grid view datasource u'r using sqlcommanad as data source is not right use dataadapter....